# Gradle dependency fallback

Tags: gradle, dependencies, fallback

Is there a way to use fallback dependency in gradle.

For example, there is dependency `com.example.module:artifact:version`.

How can I "ask" gradle do not crash building if no this artifact found on any of specified repositories, but try to use `com.example.fallback_module:vallback_artifact:fallback_version` instead?

Comment: It's tough to figure out a solution that might work. Can you update your question to add more info about the problem. What are the dependencies? Why do they have different coords? Why can they be used interchangeably? Are the versions also totally different? Be aware that any solution would compromise reproducibility ([which is why Gradle disables unavailable repos](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#repository_disabling)).

Comment: Take a look through [the dependencies section of the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/component_metadata_rules.html). There are lots of options - see if you can find something that's closest to what you want. The best solution might be just to download the artifacts and [commit them into a dir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver)!